# multiple change point analysis simultaneously for mean AND variance WITHOUT distribution assumption in R

Tags: change-point

Is there a multiple change point analysis for both the mean and the variance simultaneously, implemented in R without a distribution assumption?
I know the changepoint packet 
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/changepoint/index.html
but as far as I see, it only allows change point analysis (mean & variance simultaneously) with distribution assumptions (normal, exponential, gamma).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be some more general non-parametric methods in the cpm package: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cpm/index.html. The manual associated with the package lists three methods that are supposedly used to check for more general distributional changes (such as simultaneous mean and variance changes).
However, I haven't spent a lot of time on change-point analysis, so I can't speak for the quality of the package.

Comment: @ Jonathan Thiele: Thank's! That looks fine. I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the `ecp` package which does more general nonparametric distributional changes and even allows for multivariate data:

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ecp/

Answer (score 1):

For those looking at this thread there is now also the `changepoint.np` package for R (available on CRAN) which contains a method for a change in distribution and is currently being revamped with more specific robust changepoint methods.